# external USB 3 HDD issues

Tags: windows-10, usb

I have a dual USB 3 hub connected to the motherboard socket on a Gigabyte Z97 G1 gaming which will access pen drives without any issues.
The problem arises when I try to use an external 2.5 HDD which worked fine until the other day, in any of the USB ports (on board or hub).
It powers up (LED glowing and Drive vibrating) but can't see the drive in file explorer. Oddly I can see the drive and contents in file explorer if I plug it into my printers USB port or a TV.

All other USB devices (mouse, Keyboard,printer)
work fine.

My question is, could this be a driver issue (windows is current to 20H2), the hub failing or the motherboard?

I'd appreciate any thoughts on this. I'm hoping for a cheap fix but in the back of my mind I see an expensive rebuild coming

Comment: "My question is, could this be a driver issue" - No; There is absolutely no chance of that being the cause of the problem you describe.

Comment: Your "dual USB hub" has insufficient port power to feed your 2.5" HDD USB drive, period. It was likely marginal in first place, but after connector deterioration over time you have this problem. Get a better self-powered hub.

Comment: Certainly worth a try and a lot cheaper than what I was dreading.

Answer (score 0):

The USB-A ports on hubs are notorious for supplying minimal power.  A hub port is only required to supply 500 mA as I recall.  Some hubs have a "charge port" or something like that which are built to handle 1.5 or 2.4 amps.  A powered hub is supposed to supply at least 900 mA but not all do, and some supply more.  Ports on the computer should be able to supply at least 1.5 amps.  The drive likely works fine on the printer and TV because they provide enough power.

There's a lot of different power levels on USB.  There's 150 mA for "boot up" power.  That's the power a device is allowed to draw once plugged in and before being recognized by the computer.  Once the computer recognizes the device then the device can ask for more power.  This can be 500 mA, 900 mA, 1.5 amps, 2.4 amps, or 3 amps.  Unpowered hubs likely supply only 500 mA because it has to take the 1.5 amps that a host port is required to supply and divide that up to power connected devices and itself.

You stated this problem developed recently.  Maybe the drive is just worn a bit and needs a little bit more power.  This can be normal and expected wear or a sign of damage.  High power devices that have motors should not be used with a hub.  If a hub must be used then it should be powered.

I'm a bit surprised that you don't get a warning on the computer that the device needs more power.  I'll see that on my Macs.  I run Windows and Linux mostly in virtual machines so they are insulated from hardware issues like this.

This sounds like a power issue if the drive is fine on your TV.  Always plug it directly into a port on the computer, with no hub or lengthy cord in between.

Comment: Hi
I had considered this but it also stopped working when plugged directly into a motherboard USB 3

Comment: " Hi I had considered this but it also stopped working when plugged directly into a motherboard USB 3 "  Well, that's unfortunate.  It can still be a power issue but so many other things as well.  If the drive works on TV but not computer then I'd look more closely at the computer.  I can't rule out a damaged or worn drive.  Back up anything important on the drive somehow if possible.  Try the self powered hub as suggested by others.

Comment: trying a few investigative options whilst the powered hub is on the way, although I can't see the drive in explorer, I can see it in disk management and Paragon partition manager.
Obviously the pc is seeing the drive in some ways but not sufficiently to see the drive content. 
Would I be right in thinking it's the power draw of the drive overwhelming the case hub?

Comment: OKI purchased a powered RSTech 5 port usb 3 hub and the drive I originally posted about is still not visible in explorer but the hub is showing a flashing LERD as if the drive is being used (read/write).
It is beginning to look like a dying drive even though it is visible via my printers usb port. Time to back up data. Anyone got any other ideas before I close this thread?